# error to connect database, target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm developing an application, in which two tables of a database are connected but not the third. (This is on server. They are working fine on my local machine.)

```
 1. Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No
    connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying
    to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\Hosting.. on line 5
 2. Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in D:\Hosting.. on line 5
```

At an earlier stage, I connected to the two tables from the same database successfully, so I've checked the physical location of each table of the database. No wonder all are physically resting at the same place in the database.

Please help me to understand the problem.

**EDIT :**

```
//Page1 has something like:
$conid=mysql_connect("dxxs.db.7xx7.hostedresource.com","dxxs","Kxx3") or die();
mysql_select_db("dxxs",$conid) or die();
mysql_query(“some basic 4-5 queries depending on user’s interaction with table1”);
mysql_close($conid);
//redirection to page2 from there to page3
$conid=mysql_connect("dxxs.db.7xx7.hostedresource.com","dxxs","Kxx3") or die();
mysql_select_db("dxxs",$conid) or die();
mysql_query(“some basic 4-5 queries depending on user’s interaction with table2”);
mysql_close($conid);
//some redirection to page4
$conid=mysql_connect("dxxs.db.7xx7.hostedresource.com","dxxs","Kxx3") or die();
mysql_select_db("dxxs",$conid) or die();
mysql_query(“some basic 4-5 queries depending on user’s interaction with table3”);
mysql_close($conid);
```

Now my problem is when connecting to table 3, the server is throwing an *error as 
stated above*

Where in line 5, MySQL_connect is written. Please help me to understand why table 3 is not getting connected whereas table 1 & table 2 are able to connect. All are resting at the same database on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are calling `mysql_connect()` once for each table you are working with. You do not need to do this - you only need to connect once for each **server** you are working with.

The server is probably limiting you to 2 concurrent connections, which is why it is refusing the third.

Try calling `mysql_connect()` once at the top of your script.

Comment: No, they are three different pages, at three different levels and at end of each page am closing the connection. Thanks-any other way around!

Comment: What do you mean by `they are three different pages, at three different levels`? You mean you have `include`d some files from the main script or what? Can you show some example code that gives the problem?

Comment: I mean at 1st stage they can create as many as forms they want, they will be saved. at second stage they can edit and conform, at third stage they can finally edit only once, after which a word document and a pdf document will be generated

Comment: Please show your code from the beginning up to the line where you get the error.

Comment: its the line where connection is made `$conid=mysql_connect("datasystems.db.7xx7.hostedresource.com","datasystems","Kx3") or die();`

Comment: @letsfly I need to see the code before that line as well. I suspect you have multiple calls to `mysql_connect()` in the same script.

Comment: please check my edit in main question for the code and problem explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: @letsfly Try removing all the calls to `mysql_close()`. This happens explicitly at the end of the script anyway and I think it might help with the problem because of the way the MySQL extension reuses connections under the bonnet. I take it all these scripts are executing under the same server?

Comment: yes all the pages, their relative database and tables in it are resting on same server. I tried by removing all `mysql_close` but of no use.

Comment: This definitely smells of a concurrency problem - do you have MySQLi or PDO_mysql available on your server? I'd be interested to know if you have the same problem with either of these. Really you should be using one of these anyway, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used to write new code.

Comment: on using mysqli i got following errors
 
`Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\Hosting\7x17\..\phpinfo.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in D:\Hosting\7x17\..\phpinfo.php on line 3

Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: How much control do you have over the MySQL server? It sounds like it is in some way configured to reject a third connection. You could do with inspecting the configuration and enabling the error log and general query log in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html) to take this further.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and solved it. Try to use my code using port after `hostname:PORT`:

```
$dbh=@mysql_connect('dbxxxxxx.db.1and1.com:3306','db-username','db-password');
if (!$dbh) {
    $err_msg='Cannot connect to the database because: '.mysql_error();  
}
```